# Take notes in backend

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

Sometime I have some idea for my site and I want to write it somewhere.

I'd like to find a way to write these notes, save and read them inside Joomla, but only in the backend; I don't want to show them in the site because are personal notes.

What's the best way to take notes in the Joomla backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a notes module in the back-end of the website, go to: Extensions -> Modules, set the filter to Administrator, click on "New", select "Custom" and create the new Custom module as follows:

- Title: Website Administration Notes
- Show Title: Show
- Position: cpanel
- Status: Published
- Access: Special

with the following HTML or similar content:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #bce8f1; border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; background: #d9edf7 none repeat scroll 0 0; color: #31708f; padding: 5px 10px 5px; margin: -5px 0 15px;">
    <p style="margin: 5px 0;">To edit these notes, go to: Extensions -&gt; Modules, set filter to Administrator and click on "Website Administration Notes".</p>
</div>
<h3>To Do List</h3>
<p>1.<br />2.<br />3.</p>
<div style="border-top: 1px solid #ddd;">&nbsp;</div>
<h3>Most Recent Changes</h3>
<p>1.<br />2.<br />3.</p>
<div style="border-top: 1px solid #ddd;">&nbsp;</div>
```

The following will then be displayed in the back end of the website each time you log in:

[image: Back End Notes]

Comment: That's a nice solution, thanks. I need to go to modules page every time that I need to update the note but it's acceptable for me.

Comment: Well, you can always use neat little trick of creating anchor for direct editing of that custom module by inserting `<p><a href="index.php?option=com_modules&amp;task=module.edit&amp;id=XXX">Edit Module</a></p>` where XXX is module ID.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new Access Level (Users -> Access Levels). Add only Super Admin to the new Access Level. Then set anything associated with your notes (Articles, Categories, etc.) to that Access Level.